# Check If Field Has Been Modified

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm working on a user system, and I want to use the `beforeValidate` hook to hash the user's password with bcrypt. However, if the password is not changed, I want it to skip hashing the password. I know it's possible in MongoDB/Mongoose, but I haven't stumbled across anything comparable to Mongoose's `isModified` function.

Is there anything that I can use to check if it's modified? Or would be setting the password via an `InstanceMethod` be the only way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequelize has the `.changed()` method which can be used to check whether an attribute has been changed:

http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/instance/#changedkey-booleanarray

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Somehow I missed that in perusing the docs! Thank you.